# Incremental informations about Drools match

Tags: drools

I am trying to use Drools as an rule engine to a synchronizer. The synchronizer does some changes in the system based on some conditions which will be checked using Drools.

fireAllRules() and the matches

[image]

Suppose there can be 'matches'** m0, m1, m2 and m3 against my rules. In the image above I have shown what are the matches for two fireAllRules().

When running fireAllRules() first time, 'I get'*** matches m0, m1 and m2.

Then my synchronizer does some changes in the system. On second run of fireAllRules(), I get matches m1, m2 and m3.

What my synchronizer needs at this stage is to identify the following:

- match m0 is removed.
- matches m1 and m2 are repeated. ( old
  matches)
- match m4 is a new match.

Since Drools is an incremental pattern match-er, I am curious whether there is a way to get these information ( in the bullet points above).

** by 'match' I mean a collection of fact satisfying the 'when' part of the rule. 
So if I have two object of type Test() in working memory, a simple rule like

```
when
t : Test()
```

should have two matches m0 and m1 containing information about two Test() objects.

*** by 'I get' I mean I require Drools to provide me this. I do not know how to get this.

Comment: You must be joking - the jpg is ridiculous. You keep talking in terms of the implementation but you avoid describing the problem. Forget "match", "rule", "run", "firing", "Drools" - just describe the blasted PROBLEM in terms of your APPLICATION. (Example: Given the radius of a circle, determine the area and circumference. That's not using any of the quoted terms from above. Get it?)

Comment: Do you call fireAllRules after every fact insertion? And although, as @laune asked, what's the real business problem are you trying to solve? Maybe the problem is your approach to the problem, not the technical details you are trying to deal.

Comment: Yes, I call fireAllRules after every fact insertion.